# Photoshop CC converting image layers to video clip

Tags: photoshop, timelapse, video

I have an image sequence in Photoshop CC 2018 and have turned them into a timelapse. I want to change the speed / length of the video but I am unable to.
If I change the framerate it increases/decreases the number of frames but the time stays constant at ~5s.

How do I change my images/frames into a Video Clip? Apparently only a Video Clip will show the option to control speed but I can't find how to turn my images into the Video Clip anywhere!

Images below show my image sequence in the Layers section, then in the Timeline section (in Purple). The blue layer is a blank video layer showing the option that I require.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

[image: Video group made up of images]
[image: Blank Video Layer with speed option]

Comment: Although you are starting with still images, which is on topic here, the problem you are encountering is unique to video production only, which makes it off topic here. This would be a much better fit at [video.stackexchange.com](video.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you cannot get Photoshop to work, try `ffmpeg -i IMG_%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -vf fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`.

Comment: See [Time-lapse photography tutorial in Photoshop](https://photoshopcafe.com/timelapse.htm). End of article under heading "Processing" has some info about frame rate that might help.

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic.  It's using a photo manipulation program to work with photos that they have taken and simply trying to choose an export format that happens to be a video format.  It isn't how to edit a video, it is how to export photos in a particular format and isn't fundamentally different from asking how to export as jpg or tiff or with transparency.

Comment: Appreciate the answers. And agreed.. my problem stems from the fact these are a series of photos, not a video file. Plus I imagine this is the most appropriate place for Photoshop related questions. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

- According to [Time-lapse photography tutorial in Photoshop](https://photoshopcafe.com/timelapse.htm), the following steps may do what you want:

  > In Photoshop, choose image>open navigate to your folder of images.
  >
  > Choose the first image in the sequence only (don’t select all the images, or Photoshop will try to make a time-lapse sequence for each of the images, and you will have a mess.)
  >
  > Click the button at the bottom of the import dialog box that says “image sequence” (If the sequence is broken, the video shows how to repair the naming)
  >
  > Click ok and select a frame-rate when prompted.
- If you cannot figure out how to do what you want with Photoshop, you may consider using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/):

  ```
  ffmpeg -i IMG_%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -vf fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
  ```

  The relevant option to control the framerate is `fps=30`.

Answer (score 0):

Export your pics into your video editor and use the video editor to manipulate the speed.  At that point it's off topic.